# Authenticate users by Customer, Login and Password with Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I've got a typical Authlogic setup that I need to enhance to require Customer ID in addition to Login and Password.

I've read a bit about using a custom find method and another about using a global variable for accessing the additional parameter and a third referring to documentation about using scopes that doesn't seem to exist.

Seems like this should be easy, but I can't seem to find the right approach.

Anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In your UserSession class, add:

```
find_by_login_method :find_by_customer_id_or_login
```

In your User class, create this customer finder:

```
def self.find_by_customer_id_or_login(login)
  User.find_by_customer_id(login) || User.find_by_login(login)
end
```

This is assuming a User has both a customer_id field and a login field.

Answer (score 0):

Add a customer_id column through a migration and validate_presence_of :customer_id on your model. It doesn't have anything to do with authlogic. Unless there is more that you are trying to do.